# Why is my model being recognized as a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a controller that calls a model method:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  item_num = params[:item_num] || "0001"
  @product = Scraper.lookup_item(item_num)
end
```

Here is the `Scraper` model:

```
class Scraper < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'mechanize'

  def self.lookup_item(item_num)
    # code goes here
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error?

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'lookup_item' for Scraper:Module`

Comment: Is there a line ```module Scraper``` in your ```config/application.rb```?
Not posting an answer because I'm only 90% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this error before. `grep` your project to see if `module Scraper` is defined anywhere. If it is, remove it, or change it to class instead of module.

Comment: I'm a complete idiot. My whole project is called Scraper so yes it's defined everywhere haha.